# Print log between two dates

Tags: text-processing, grep, logs, date

I want to get log details between two dates but I am unable to print anything with the command:

```
egrep "^\[MAY 16 11:00:00\]"  alert.log -A 10000 | egrep "^\[MAY 16 16:30:00\]" -B 10000
```

Comment: The date is like this  Mon May 15 15:32:01 2017

Comment: Your date example in the comment here regarding the log file source does not match the case of your example egrep search string.  Please clarify if the log actually looks like, or what exactly you want your search string to match.  Maybe include a small snippet from the log itself?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/May 16 11:00:00/,/May 16 16:30:00/p' /path/to/inputfile
```

With `grep`, I think the problems may be firstly the order of your parameters -- you're putting the `-A` and `-B` arguments *after* the input file, so `grep` is probably trying to read files called `-A`, `-B`, and `10000`; and secondly, that you are not escaping your square braces.  Your pipeline could work as follows:

```
grep -E -A10000 'May 16 11:00:00' alert.log | grep -E -B10000 'May 16 16:30:00'
```

Note that these will only work if you actually have a log entry that matches the exact timestamp for which you are searching; adjust accordingly for the first and last entry you want as the limits of your search.

Comment: Thanks Dope but your SED does show nothing. The format of date in my TEXT file is like this (Mon May 15 15:32:01 2017). I ran your command and did not get any output

Comment: Next time compose your question in a manner that reflects what you're searching for; I shall update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `egrep` based on the example you provided:

```
egrep "May 16 1[1-6]:..:.." /path/to/file | egrep -v "May .. 16:[3-5][1-9]:[0-9][1-9]"
```

Comment: Thanks FCTW. But still i am getting nothing.

Comment: Please clarify the actual log contents as I asked in the comment above.

Comment: Mon May 15 15:32:00 2017
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Mon May 15 15:32:00 2017
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Mon May 15 15:32:00 2017
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Using deprecated SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.
Mon May 15 15:32:00 2017